# What does "married to the former Jane Doe" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

From the back cover of Henry Kissinger's [Diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_(book)) book:

> Dr. Kissinger is married to the former Nancy Maginnes and is the father of two children by a previous marriage.

What does "is married to the former Nancy Maginnes" mean?  Is Maginnes Nancy's maiden name?

What is the purpose of the adjective "former" instead of simply "is married to Nancy Maginnes"?  Can we use it for all cases where the wife doesn't update her last name to match her husband's name, or is the adjective "former" only used for special occasions, such as when the maiden name is linked to famous families / royalty / celebrities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "former" indicates that Nancy Maginnes used to be her name.   Yes, that's her maiden name.   No, the word "former" isn't limited to either special occasions or to people's names.   Nancy Sharon Kissinger is still married to that former U.S. Secretary of State.

No, we would not use "the former Nancy Maginnes" if she had kept that name.  Rather, she did update her name to match her husband's.   That's *why* the word "former" works here.

Comment: If a celebrity uses a stage name but we are not sure whether he has legally changed his name, can we also use "former" as well? For example: "Sir Elton John, formerly Reginald Kenneth Dwight, had a difficult relationship with his father, Stanley Dwight, who opposed him to pursue his passion for music when he was a teenager."

Comment: Yes.  That sentence works quite well.  I prefer the phrasing "his pursuing" rather than "him to pursue", but that's a separate question.   Edit:  Oh, but you're not sure whether he still uses his birth name?  In that case, don't.  We use "former" and "formerly" for things that were true but no longer are.

Comment: He legally changed his name to Elton Hercules John in 1972, and received his knighthood under that very name in 1998.  The boys down Harrow way get to remember him as a local boy made good, of course.  Still, "formerly" is correct.

Comment: "formerly" is basically short for "formerly known as", which just means people used to refer to somebody by a different name than they do now.  As such, whether it's a legal name change or not is actually pretty much irrelevant.  It does, however, generally imply that they are *not* actually referred to by that name anymore (it's not still an alias they use in some contexts, for example).